# Point to point Request-Response Behavior with libp2p

Tags: libp2p, point-to-point

Using libp2p, is there a way to write a network behavior that doesn’t hit the entire swarm, but goes directly to a peer and only that peer?

More generally, is there a way within libp2p to communicate exclusively (request/response) to particular peer that you are currently connected to?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use [gossipsub](https://docs.libp2p.io/concepts/publish-subscribe/) and subscribe to a specific topic between peers. You can create a custom behaviour that implements gossipsub and request/response. [Here is an example](https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/blob/master/examples/chat-tokio.rs#L85-L94) of how to implement multiple behaviours in Rust.

I'm trying to do something similar but need multiple peers to subscribe to a topic.

[Here is a list](https://docs.rs/libp2p/0.39.1/libp2p/swarm/trait.NetworkBehaviour.html#implementors) of all implementors for the NetworkBehaviour in Rust. At the time of writing, it looks like your options are:

- Floodsub
- Identify
- Mdns
- Ping
- Relay
- DummyBehaviour
- Throttled
- Gossipsub
- Toggle
- RequestResponse
- Kademlia

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who finds this answer post 2022, the preferred solution would be the [request-response](https://docs.rs/libp2p-request-response/latest/libp2p_request_response/) network behavior.

An example of how to use this library can be found in the library's tests: https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/blob/master/protocols/request-response/tests/ping.rs